# VB.Net build error targetting .Net 2 in VS2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have created a new VB Console application targetting .Net Framework 2.0.
When I try to build I get the following error:

> Error 1   Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR2" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuildTaskHost.exe" exists and can be run.

MSBuildTaskHost.exe does exist in the specified directory and can be run (displays a blank console window if I run from Windows Explorer).

Searching found some similar problems with people using a build server (I am just building from the IDE) and when the username is longer then 20 characters, but mine is 17 characters including the domain and backslash character.

It seems this is something to do with compiling resources but my project does not contain any .resx file (just a single code module).

Computer is running Windows 8.1 64-bit. Build configuration is set to Any CPU.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like 32bit and 64bit is being mixed up. It's looking for x86 (i.e. 32bit) task host. Do you use any 32bit libraries by any chance? Try setting all project's compile target to x86 and see what happens. Also explicitly select x86 compile target. Play around with the settings.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758772/generateresource-fails-for-net-3-5-application-when-net-4-5-has-been-installed

Comment: I tried changing the build configuration to x86 and it now builds without error. Interestingly, I change it back to Any CPU and it still builds without error!
The only reference I have added on top of what I get as standard with a console application is to IWshRuntimeLibrary which I'm using to create a desktop shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the link Hans, but I've already seen that. That is why I stated in my question that my username is less than 20 characters long.

Comment: Hmmmm. Seems like problem is intermittent. I open the project again and I get the error when try to rebuild. Choose rebuild again immediately and it works.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708997/generateresource-task-clr2-runtime-error